# NoClassDefFoundError error with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I get this runtime error sometimes after compiling and opening the app. 
Here's what I have in the gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

and here's the logcat trace (actual error is only in the very last lines)

```
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lretrofit2/Response;)
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method retrofit2.Response.body, referenced from method com.myproject.BaseController.hasOkStatus
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 64810: Lretrofit2/Response;.body ()Ljava/lang/Object;
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0001
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lretrofit2/Response;)
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject I/dalvikvm: Could not find method retrofit2.Response.isSuccess, referenced from method com.myproject.BaseController.parseResult
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 64811: Lretrofit2/Response;.isSuccess ()Z
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient$1; interface 8642 'Lokhttp3/Interceptor;'
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient$1;' failed
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.myproject.rest.RestClient$1', referenced from method com.myproject.rest.RestClient.getInstance
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2661 (Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient$1;) in Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient;
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient$1; interface 8642 'Lokhttp3/Interceptor;'
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient$1;' failed
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x51d5 at 0x0b in Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient;.getInstance
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xeee1 at 0x10 in Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient;.getInstance
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x986d at 0x13 in Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient;.getInstance
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xee81 at 0x1a in Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient;.getInstance
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfd2d at 0x3d in Lbr/org/myproject/rest/RestClient;.getInstance
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-27 17:54:37.442 29161-29161/com.myproject W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d5d58)
04-27 17:54:38.342 29161-29161/com.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.myproject, PID: 29161
                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myproject.rest.RestClient$1
                                                                           at com.myproject.rest.RestClient.getInstance(RestClient.java:29)
                                                                           at com.myproject.features.auth.control.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:36)
```

**[Edit] Here's the offending code:**

```
public static Retrofit getInstance(){

        if(instance != null) return instance;

        Interceptor headerInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");

                return chain.proceed(originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .header("Content-Type", mediaType.toString())
                        .addHeader("token", "asdfasdfadfafdadfa")
                        .build());
            }
        };
```

Comment: Done, but the reason I did not post it in the first place was that the same code was working before (apparently)

Comment: Does that code snippet include RestClient line 29?  Because that's where the problem is.  And if it was working "before", do you know what's changed since then?

Comment: Thank you nasch, I just posted the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so appearently the reason for this error was that I was using multidex support but my custom Application class did not extend MultiDexApplication.java, as per instructions detailed in this page:

[http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/building/multidex.html][1]